# Pass custom class property as lambda in method

Tags: c#

The Scope of this Project is just a console application and I get a pretty annoying 
The error I get when trying to pass the value:
Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type 'DungeonRunner.Ability'

The function where I want to pass the parameter:

```
public void UseSpell(Ability ability)
            {
                var SpellToUse = this.CharClass.GetAbilities();
                //Get all Abilites
                this.CharClass.GetAbilities();
                if (this.MP == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot use advanced Abilities, drink a Mana Potion to restore Mana");
                    var UsedSpell = SpellToUse.First();
                    this.MP -= UsedSpell.ManaCost1; //This line is unnecessary because the first spell costs nothing

                }
                else if(this.MP >= 0)
                {

                    var UsedSpell = SpellToUse.Find(abilityName => abilityName.SpellName1 == ability.SpellName1);
                    this.MP -= UsedSpell.ManaCost1;

                }
```

The class I reference to:

```
namespace DungeonRunner
{
    public class Ability
    {
        private int ManaCost;
        private int SpellDamage;
        private string SpellName;

        public Ability(int manaCost, int spellDamage, string spellName)
        {
            ManaCost = manaCost;
            SpellDamage = spellDamage;
            SpellName = spellName;
        }

        public int ManaCost1
        {
            get => ManaCost;
            set => ManaCost = value;
        }

        public int SpellDamage1
        {
            get => SpellDamage;
            set => SpellDamage = value;
        }

        public string SpellName1
        {
            get => SpellName;
            set => SpellName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the value I try to pass:

```
`MyCharacter.UseSpell(ability => ability.SpellName == spellname)`;
```

The question is: How can I possibly optimize this so that the error goes away.
It may be that I'll need to change the paramter. But I dont think it's needed.

Comment: Why not calling the method `MyCharacter.UseSpell(ability);`?

Comment: Do you want to provide the `Ability` that has the specified `SpellName`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes. It's saved in the list.

Comment: Providing a delegate to `UseSpell` assumes that method searches for the correct ability itself by iterating the list. On the other hand, if you provide a certain `Ability` to that method, the search has to be done in front by the client. However it´s unclear what you actually want. Should `USeSpell` *expect* an `Ability` or *search* for a matching one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list with all abilities is called abilities you can write the following code;

```
Ability usedAbility = abilities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SpellName1 == spellname);
if(usedAbility != null)
{
    MyCharacter.UseSpell(usedAbility);
}
```

With `FirstOrDefault` you're getting the first `Ability` with the spellname. I added the null check because if there is no `Ability` with that name you will get `null` from `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was quite struggling with the lambda expression :)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two ways you can do.

The first is provide the actual `Ability` to your method and let it do something with that instance:

```
public void UseSpell(Ability ability)
{
    // do something with the provided ability
}
```

This way your *client* has to search for the correct ability. To do so it has to know all abilities:

```
UseSpell(myAbilities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Spellname == "MySpell"));
```

The other opportunity is that `UseSpell` searches for an `Ability` itself based on some condition, which you can provide by a delegate. However that assumes that `UseSpell` has **access** to all abilities in order to search for the "right" one:

```
public void UseSpell(Func<Ability, bool> predicate)
{
    // get all abilities
    var allAbilties = ...;
    // get the one that matches the condition
    var ability = allAbilities.FirstOrDefault(predicate)
}
```

Now the client only provides the criterion, but not the entire list of abilities:

```
UseSpell(x => x.Spellname == "MySpell");
```

So depending on where your list of all abilites is located, either the one or the other approach might be better. The result is the same in both cases. However the semantics are different.

Answer (score 0):

Reference is wrong. Do the following

```
MyCharacter.Where(ability => ability.SpellName == spellname).Foreach(ability => UseSpell(ability));
```